UICollectionView Padding/EdgeInsets for views in children
I have a UICollectionView which uses a UICollectionViewFlowLayout to layout its children. These children will have varying heights, so I need to adjust the UICollectionView such that the elements are bottom-aligned and not center-aligned
This is what I have

And this is what I want

I tried using
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets

But it is for an entire section I need it only for its elements
Any Idea how to resolve this?

Not quite clear ... do you want the cell contents to be "bottom-aligned"? Or, do you want it to look (potentially) like this? https://i.sstatic.net/WHeq6KwX.png

No, the cells will have different heights, but it should be bottom-aligned, Currently, it comes centered. (Check the images in question)

You really need to provide a more detailed description of what you want to do... Is this about it? https://i.sstatic.net/OlXFbnP1.png ... will you have a Max and Min height? Will you potentially have hundreds or even thousands of rows?

Yes i need it like that only
